# How to close a tkinter window when button pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def _error_message(self, message: str):
    self._error_window = tkinter.Toplevel()
    title = tkinter.Label(master = self._error_window,
        text = message, font = DEFAULT)
    title.grid(row = 0, padx = 12, pady = 12, sticky = tkinter.EW)

    ok_error_button = tkinter.Button(master=self._error_window, text='OK',
        font= DEFAULT, command = self._error_window.destroy())
    ok_error_button.grid(row = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    self._error_window.grab_set()
```

I want to make pressing the "ok" button on a window close a window how do I do that?

Comment: Are you aware of the `MessageBox` widget? Might save you a few lines, as long as you only need a label and a button in your popup. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the button's command to `self.destroy`
Add this before you initialize the button:

```
def destroy(self)
    self._error_window.destroy()
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
def quit(self):
    self._error_window.destroy()
```

Comment: I may be mistaken (I probably am), but I don't think this will work unless he/she does `root = tkinter.Toplevel()` instead of `top = tkinter.Toplevel()` .

Comment: Whups, you changed it on me! =)

Comment: command =self._close_error_window())  and .........                                    

    def _close_error_window(self):      and......                                  

        self._error_window.destroy()